# What 中二日 means?

Tags: grammar, time

A sentence from [こころ - 三話](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/773_14560.html#midashi130)

> それから中二日おいてちょうど三日目の午後だったと思う。

Due to 中二日, I'm uncertain about timeframe in this sentence. Based on what I know, 中二日 means a third business day. Does it mean

> After that, three days have passed and it was afternoon of the third day.

Am I wrong?

Also, is おいて here doesn't mean 居る but 於いて which means で?

Comment: In case you're wondering, it's pronounced なかふつか【HLLHH】.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `中二日` means there're two days between today and three days from now.

That `おいて` means "leave an interval" and different from `於いて`. `中二日おいて` means leaving two days interval, `二日おいて` will mean the same as well.

Comment: It might be better if your answer explained おいて is 置いて.

Comment: Note that 中... and …おいて can be different. 一日おいたカレー usually the curry of the next day. 中一日 would be hardly used for this case, but if it were, it would mean the curry after two days (27th, if I cook curry today).